# Django Admin - custom column in first row isn't rendered properly

Tags: python, django, django-admin

We've came across a weird problem. There is a `Transaction` model and it's admin has a custom column `revert` which sends POST to server.

The weird thing is that `revert` in the first line doesn't work. I just doesn't render the `<form>` tag. Other rows works correctly.

```
@admin.register(Transaction)
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['code', 'created', 'modified', 'wallet', 'title', 'amount', 'invoice_link','revert']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        self.request = request
        return qs

    def revert(self, obj: Transaction):
        if obj.pk:
            html = render_to_string("alex_wallets/transactions/revert_block.html", context={'transaction': obj},
                                    request=self.request)
            return mark_safe(format_html(html))
```

**revert_block.html**

```
<div>
    <form onsubmit="return confirm('Naozaj chcete vytvoriť opačnú transakciu?')"
          action="{% url "wallets:revert_transaction" transaction.pk %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button style=" color: #fff; background-color: #00D996; border: 0; border-radius:4px; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px;" type="submit">Vrátiť
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is an `html` of the first row (column revert):

```
<td class="field-revert"><div>

        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="agpE7aEExG19YJ3n8wDv88sC7J7u7aHXa5Od3vVJptA6t0on1gGENECaTt2Qp7hb">
        <button style=" color: #fff; background-color: #00D996; border: 0; border-radius:4px; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px;" type="submit">Vrátiť
        </button>

</div></td>
```

And this is an `html` of other than first row revert column:

```
<td class="field-revert"><div>
    <form onsubmit="return confirm('Naozaj chcete vytvoriť opačnú transakciu?')" action="/alex/transakcie/transactions/revert/45/" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Pc7Pt41tXgMUyZyKOORUb2gQutkqCkjpP1woppiyP3lR3gTKHyU3QyqogdfMUhTD">
        <button style=" color: #fff; background-color: #00D996; border: 0; border-radius:4px; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px;" type="submit">Vrátiť
        </button>
    </form>
</div></td>
```

The same applies on `inline` form.

Do you know where is the problem?

**EDIT:**

It's always the first row. I can reorder the rows and always it is the first one which doesn't render properly. And I've checked it in `django-jet` and built in raw `django-admin` too. Both have this problem.

**EDIT2:**

In debugger, I can see that the `html` is always rendered properly, even for the first row.

**EDIT3:**

It's browser independent. The same happens on `Chrome` and on `Firefox`

**EDIT4:**

So I'm closer to the root. I've noticed that it is rendered properly but browser deletes the first form. It's probably, because the `changelist` table is surrounded by another form by default but don't know what to do.

Comment: Could the first row have a pk of 0?

Comment: @DanielRoseman If you mean pk of the object then no. Moreover, the same thing happens when I reorder rows. It's always the first row no matter which object is it

Comment: @DanielRoseman and it wouldnt render anything in such case I think.

Comment: Did you consider making custom admin action - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/ ? This seems to be more conventional/idiomatic approach.

Comment: @EugenePrikazchikov Admin actions are a great tool but this time I needed to do this the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that there is a big default `form` surrounding the whole `changelist` table and browsers don't like nested forms. So we needed to do it other way.

So I've created a `js` code which creates a new form dynamically when needed.

**revert template**

```
<div>

    <button class="postbtn" data-csrf="{{ csrf_token }}"
            data-action="{% url "wallets:revert_transaction" transaction.pk %}"
            style=" color: #fff; background-color: #00D996; border: 0; border-radius:4px; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px;"
            type="button">Vrátiť
    </button>
</div>
```

**then I've created a `buttonpost.js`**

```
function nonAjaxPost(action, input) {
    'use strict';
    var form;
    form = jQuery('<form />', {
        action: action,
        method: 'post',
        style: 'display: none;'
    });
    if (typeof input !== 'undefined' && input !== null) {
        jQuery.each(input, function (name, value) {
            jQuery('<input />', {
                type: 'hidden',
                name: name,
                value: value
            }).appendTo(form);
        });
    }
    form.appendTo('body').submit();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('button[class="postbtn"]').click(function () {
        if (confirm("Potvrďte vrátenie transakcie")) {
            var ths = jQuery(this);
            var url = ths.attr('data-action');
            var csrf = ths.attr('data-csrf');

            nonAjaxPost(url, {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf});
        }
    })
});
```

Which can be included using `class Media`:

```
class ....Admin(..):
    class Media:
        js = ['...buttonpost.js']
```

The same way it can be included into `AdminInline`